# Iterating over list and adding panda dataframe columns is incredibly slow in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to iterate over a large list so that I can update some values in a dataframe. However, the result is that its too slow its making this code unusable in a production environment. I have tried many alternatives but cant figure out a good way to fix it.

#### Initial Code Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1], "B": [2], "C": [3]})
list = ["D", "E", "F"]

for x in list:
    if x not in df:
        df[x] = 0

print(df)
{"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 0, "E": 0, "F": 0}
```

My performance test is showing a few seconds total for around 3k items in the list. Any idea how to speed this up?

EDIT:

I switched from looping through a list and adding new columns directly to df. Now im creating an ordered dictionary of the columns I want to add. Then I am turning that into df2 and appending to df. I will not mark this complete because I am sure there's still a faster way.

#### Update Code Example:

```
dict = {}
for x in list:
    if x not in df:
        dict[x] = 0

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict, index=[0])
df = df.append(df2)
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question and put there sample (small) input data and expected output?

Comment: alright, how is that?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3})` throws an error. Is this correct code?

Comment: No this is just example code. I cannot publish my actual code, its using excel files and huge lists of strings for its data sources.

Comment: Can you produce *working* minimal example? The example doesn't have to be with original data, but rather something we can-paste and work with.

Comment: The code snippet you posted is not clear on what you are trying to achieve. You also seem to be confusing a dataframe with a dict in your code. You need to post a good question if you want a good answer. Generally, you want avoid looping through a dataframe, and there are ways to achieve that.

Comment: I think its confusing because the dataframe is just a bunch of columns with only one row.

Answer (score 0):

You might try testing out different approaches with `timeit`.

Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import timeit

test_one_setup = '''
import pandas as pd
'''

test_one = '''
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, index=[0])
l = ["A", "C", "D"]
for x in l:
    if x not in df:
        df[x] = 0
#
#    A  B  C  D
# 0  1  2  3  0
#
'''

print (timeit.timeit(setup = test_one_setup,
                     stmt = test_one,
                     number = 1000)) 

test_two_setup = '''
import pandas as pd
'''

test_two = '''
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3}, index=[0])
l = ["A", "C", "D"]
df2 = df.apply(lambda x:[0] if x.name in l else x)
#
#    A  B  C
# 0  0  2  0
#
'''

print (timeit.timeit(setup = test_two_setup,
                     stmt = test_two,
                     number = 1000))
```

I'm still a little unclear about your example code, as the mutated dataframe that you provide as output is not quite what I get from your code.

You may want to review the code in your question and provide a minimal, working example that demonstrates clearly what your input is, what your logic is, what output you expect. Then edit your question to reflect what you're really trying to do.

Hopefully this helps with performance testing, in any case.